# How to determine the concentration of oxygen in a nitrogen/oxygen mixture?

Tags: physical-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, gas-laws

I need to prepare a 10% oxygen in nitrogen mixture for an aerobic reaction I'm developing in lab and I found an old instrument in someone else's lab that controls the flow of two gases. So I am able to control the "percentage" of both gases in the mixture using this manifold.

However, I want to test whether or not that thing is calibrated and how exact/precise it is since I don't want to report in a paper that I'm using 10% oxygen when it is actually 20 or 30 or 50%. What is the easiest way to determine the percentage/partial pressure of this gas mixture that will give me reliable results?

I thought about physical-chemical methods such as weighing the mixture and based on basic thermodynamic equations determine its partial pressures but I think a chemical method would be more interesting, such as reacting a known volume of gas with something that would consume the oxygen in a known stoichiometry. Any ideas?

Comment: Pyrogallol is your friend.

Comment: There are commercial oxygen sensors. Gas chromatographs can also be used but you need special columns and then gas standards. Pyrogallol will not help.

Comment: Intro lab: https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/Westfield_State_University/Chem0103_Chemistry_of_the_Life_Sciences_(Theis)/05%3A_Labs/5.01%3A_Chemistry_labs/5.1.02%3A_Oxygen_in_air